# PSTricks-NODES. How can I put 'Ñ' inside a circleNODE?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node, spanish

I want to type Ñ inside a circlenode, but it don´t appear in the final result.
At the example, in the 3rd line of code.

Are there any solution?

```
 \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(12,6) %\malla
 \rput(-1,-1){$\circlenode{V}{\textcolor{blue}{Vigo}}$}
 \rput(0,2){$\circlenode{C}{\textcolor{yellow}{Coruña}}$}
 \rput(2,0){$\circlenode{S}{\textcolor{red}{Scq}}$}
 \rput(4,2){$\circlenode{P}{\textcolor{green}{Po}}$}

 \ncarc[arcangle=33]{->}{V}{C}
 \naput*{\small $45$}

 \ncarc[arcangle=11]{->}{S}{P}
 \ncput*{\small $25$}

 \ncarc[arcangle=75]{->}{S}{P}
 \ncput*{\small $15$}

 \end{pspicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(12,6) %\malla
 \rput(-1,-1){\circlenode{V}{\textcolor{blue}{Vigo}}}
 \rput(0,2){\circlenode{C}{\textcolor{magenta}{Coru\~na}}}
 \rput(2,0){\circlenode{S}{\textcolor{red}{Scq}}}
 \rput(4,2){\circlenode{P}{\textcolor{green}{Po}}}

 \ncarc[arcangle=33]{->}{V}{C}
 \naput*{\small $45$}

 \ncarc[arcangle=11]{->}{S}{P}
 \ncput*{\small $25$}

 \ncarc[arcangle=75]{->}{S}{P}
 \ncput*{\small $15$}

 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Suggestions:

- Don't use yellow foreground with white background unless you want to make the readers feel uncomfortable.

### Edit:

Based on  your comments below.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
 \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(5,3) %\malla
 \rput(-1,-1){\circlenode{V}{\textcolor{blue}{Vigo}}}
 \rput(0,2){\circlenode{C}{\textcolor{magenta}{Coru\~na}}}
 \rput(2,0){\circlenode{S}{\textcolor{red}{Scq}}}
 \rput(4,2){\circlenode{P}{\textcolor{green}{Po}}}

 \ncarc[arcangle=33]{->}{V}{C}
 \naput*{\small 45 \euro}

 \ncarc[arcangle=11]{->}{S}{P}
 \ncput*{\small 25 \euro}

 \ncarc[arcangle=75]{->}{S}{P}
 \ncput*{\small 15 \euro}

 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:* I don't know whether or not a space is needed between the number and the euro symbol. Please ask appropriate experts for this confusion.

Comment: :-) Thank you for all. Perfect Solution. And you´re right with the yellow/white colors :-) I know, but i was testing PSTricks NODES :-)

Comment: @clic-me Abusing on you,    Do you know how i  can type the Euros symbol at the numbers over the arcs?
I use...
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\DeclareInputText{128}{\euro}

Comment: @MikaIke: I don't understand what you want to achieve. What does it mean "Euros symbol at the numbers over the arcs"? I cannot imagine it. By the way, you might forget to upvote my answer. :-)

Comment: @clicl-me   
similar to this: http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/2456/snap2185.png Euro symbol similar to Dollar symbol

Comment: Yes, with the eurosymbol i have the same problem. Eurosymbol don´t works well in math mode.I realize after view your example.

Answer (score 4):

use `\textit`:

```
 \rput(0,2){$\circlenode{C}{\textit{\textcolor{yellow}{Coruña}}}$}
```

you can't use accent characters inside math. However, you also need

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Yes, I use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} but the question is only for circlenode. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: that is the reason why _complete_ example documents make _always_ sense.